# VB6 equivalent for SQL 2K float data type?

Tags: vb6

Does anyone know VB6 equivalent for SQL 2K float data type? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be a Double

Here's a nice [cross reference](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=97).